# Как работают await async

Tags: c#, async-await, асинхронность

Прочитал много литературы но пока никак не могу понять как работает `await` и `async`. Ну хоть убейте. Везде примеры с httpclient, но для меня они не понятны. Пытаюсь разобраться сам.
Вот что я понял:

> Как только наш код встречает await
>   происходит возврат управления. После
>   завершения ожидаемой операции метод
>   восстанавливается. Точнее продолжает
>   выполнение с того места, на котором
>   остановился, когда столкнулся с await.

Хорошо, я написал пару строк кода(возможно просто что-то сделал не так)

```
async Task myMethod() {
    int sum = 0;
    await SomeCycleAsync();
    Console.WriteLine("выполнился цикл2");
}
async Task SomeCycleAsync() {
    var myTask = await ResultOfCycle();

    Console.WriteLine("выполнился цикл1");
}
async Task < int > ResultOfCycle() {
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000000000; i++) {
        sum += i;
    }
    return sum;
}

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    myMethod();
}
```

1. В методе `myMethod` встречается слово `await` и, на сколько я понимаю, управление должна перейти обратно в `form_load`, верно?
2. Во время выполнения метода `SomeCycleAsync` встречается `await`, т.е. по логике управление должно перейти к `Console.WriteLine("выполнился цикл2");` Но результат работы такой:

> выполнился цикл1
>
> выполнился цикл2

Объясните мне пожалуйста почему? Совсем не понимаю

Comment: Так у вас все в одном потоке, поэтому и результат такой. Попробуйте поэкспериментировать с потоками.

Comment: > В методе myMethod встречается слово await и на сколько я понимаю управление должна перейти обратно в form_load, верно?

`await` - это оператор, который говорит "ждать, пока не будет получен результат". Управление не переходит куда-то - поток в этот момент останавливается и ждет, пока `SomeCycleAsync` не вернет результат. Весь смысл в том, чтобы отправить задание на обработку, заняться своими делами, и вызвать `await` только тогда, когда необходим результат асинхронной функции. Так можно довольно гибко работать с тормозными операциями без блокирования и полноценной многопоточности.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/hh156528.aspx

Answer (score 42):

Смотрите.

Сами по себе `async`/`await` не включают таинственным образом многопоточность/асинхронность. Они лишь создают условия, при которых эту самую асинхронность легко реализовать.

На самом деле, когда вызывается `async`-метод, происходит следующее.

1. Начинает синхронно выполняться `async`-метод. Если этот метод заканчивается до первого `await`, результат доставляется синхронно, и из метода возвращается *уже закончившийся*, завершённый `Task`.
2. Если в процессе выполнения встретился `await`, система проверяет, отработало ли уже задание, на которое вызывался `await`. Если это задание отработало, то подставляется его результат, и синхронное выполнение продолжается дальше.
3. Если задание, на которое происходит `await`, ещё не отработало, в этот момент из метода возвращается *незавершённый* `Task`. В этой точке внешний код получает управление и продолжает выполняться. Например, этот код может записать `Task` в переменную и продолжать заниматься своими делами. Или он может выполнить `await` на полученный `Task`, и поскольку этот `Task` ещё не завершён, внешний код в этот момент аналогично отдаст управление ещё более внешнему коду, и. т. д.
4. Когда `Task`, на который происходит `await`, завершится (произведя результат или исключение), код после `await` возобновит свою работу.

---

В вашем случае происходит следующее:

1. Вызывается `Form1_Load`.
2. Выполняется строчка `myMethod();`. Этот код произведёт `Task`, который впоследствии будет просто проигнорирован.
3. Начинает выполняться код метода `myMethod`. Выполняется синхронно `int sum = 0;`. Для выполнения следующей строчки для начала нужно выполнить метод `SomeCycleAsync` а затем `await` на результирующий `Task`.
4. Начинается выполнение `SomeCycleAsync`. Для получения `Task`'а, по которому нужно делать `await`, запускается метод `ResultOfCycle`.
5. Начинается выполнение `ResultOfCycle()`. Поскольку нигде в нём нету асинхронных вызовов, он выполняется полностью синхронно. Из метода возвращается завершённый `Task`.
6. Управление возвращается в `SomeCycleAsync`. Выполняется `await` на `Task`, полученный в предыдущем пункте. Поскольку этот `Task` уже завершён, в переменную `myTask` просто записывается `int`-результат. Выполняется строчка `Console.WriteLine("выполнился цикл1");`. На этом выполнение метода `SomeCycleAsync` оканчивается. Поскольку в нём не было асинхронного ожидания, возвращается завершённый `Task`.
7. Управление возвращается в метод `myMethod()`. Начинает выполняться `await` на полученный `Task`. Поскольку `Task` завершён, ничего не происходит, метод продолжает синхронно выполняться. Срабатывает строчка `Console.WriteLine("выполнился цикл2");`, метод заканчивается, возвращая завершённый `Task`.
8. Управление возвращается в `Form_Load`. Полученный `Task` игнорируется, выполнение завершается.

---

Для ваших целей правильнее было бы явно запускать вычисления асинхронным образом. Например, так:

```
async Task myMethod() {
    await SomeCycleAsync();
    Console.WriteLine("выполнился цикл-2");
}

async Task SomeCycleAsync() {
    Console.WriteLine("стартует цикл");
    // это запускает длинное вычисление на пуле потоков
    var result = await Task.Run(ResultOfCycle);
    Console.WriteLine("выполнился цикл, результат: " + result);
}

int ResultOfCycle()
{
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000000000; i++)
        sum += i;
    return sum;
}

private async void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    await myMethod();
}
```

Comment: Так `await myMethod();` все равно создаст блокировку текущего потока. Разве нет?

Comment: @iRumba: Нет, не создаёт — если метод `myMethod` написан правильно (и сам не блокирует поток). Поскольку async/await — кооперативная многозадачность, async-методы должны быть реализованы без ошибок, чтобы всё работало как надо.

Comment: @iRumba: Блокировка будет лишь до первого await внутри myMethod. Автор метода обязан позаботиться, чтобы это было недолго.

Comment: а если написать вместо `await myMethod();` `var t = await myMethod();`?

Comment: Вообще await означает ожидание завершения задачи, а значит Form1_Load повиснет в ожидании, разве нет?

Comment: @iRumba: Вариант с `var t` ничем не отличается. `myMethod()` возвращает `Task`, а await асинхронно дожидается окончания работы этого таска.

Comment: А вы на 100% в этом уверены. Мне почему то думается, что дожидается он таки СИНХРОННО завершения асинхронного потока.

Comment: @iRumba: Да, на 100%. И вы можете тоже сами убедиться, если хотите, при помощи логгинга.

Comment: @VladD Можно ли на интуитивном уровне считать, что await играет роль "return" и возвращает Task?

Comment: @user190794: С «физической» точки зрения — да, в момент выполнения `await` (_если_ ожидаемый таск ещё не завершён!) происходит выход из метода.

Answer (score 3):

У тебя `ResultOfCycle()` должна вернуть `Task<int>`, но возвращает `sum`, которая является просто `int`. В самом методе нету второго потока, в котором он бы выполнялся.
`Await` пишется перед объектом `Task` или методом, возвращающим объект `Task`.

Пример для `Task`(вызов функции, которая ничего не возвращает):

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    My();

    for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        Console.WriteLine($"* {i*1000}");
    }
    Console.ReadLine();
}

static async void My()
{
    await GetMessage(3000);
}

static Task GetMessage(int time)
{
    return Task.Run(() => {
        Thread.Sleep(time);
        Console.WriteLine($"zxzxz {time.ToString()}");
    });
}
```

Пример для `Task<T>`(вызов функции, которая возвращает объект типа `T` или в нашем случае `string`):

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    My();

    for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        Console.WriteLine($"* {i*1000}");
    }
    Console.ReadLine();
}

static async void My()
{
    string message = await GetMessage(3000);
    Console.WriteLine(message);
}

static Task<string> GetMessage(int time)
{
    return Task.Run(() => {
        Thread.Sleep(time);
        return $"zxzxz {time.ToString()}";
    });
}
```