# C# зависание скачивание

Tags: c#, ftp, download

Скачивание:Когда нажимаю Кнопку Download Form1 перестает отвечать после того как файл скачался Form1 начинает работать как это исправить.

> **Как сделать так чтобы Form1 не зависал а заднем плане скачивался файл?**

```
    private void Download_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        FTPDownload(appPath, "file.7z", "xxxx xxx.com", "username", "pass");
        }

public Boolean FTPDownload(string filePath, string fileName, string FTPAddress, string username, string password)
        {
            FtpWebRequest requestFTP;
            try
            {
                FileStream outputStream = new FileStream(filePath + "\\" + fileName, FileMode.Create);
                requestFTP = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create(new Uri("ftp://" + FTPAddress + "/" + fileName));
                requestFTP.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DownloadFile;
                requestFTP.UseBinary = true;
                requestFTP.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(username, password);
                FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)requestFTP.GetResponse();
                Stream ftpStream = response.GetResponseStream();
                long cl = response.ContentLength;
                int bufferSize = 1048;
                int readCount;
                byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
                int totalReadBytesCount = 0;
                readCount = ftpStream.Read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                while (readCount > 0)
                {
                    outputStream.Write(buffer, 0, readCount);
                    readCount = ftpStream.Read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                    label1.Text = readCount.ToString();
                }
                ftpStream.Close();
                outputStream.Close();
                response.Close();
                return true;
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Так вынеси скачивание в отдельный поток

Comment: или дергать очередь сообщений если чтение происходит все же порциями.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно просто вынести скачивание файла в отдельный поток.

```
private async void Download_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    bool result = await FTPDownload(appPath, "file.7z", "xxxx xxx.com", "username", "pass");
}

public async Task<bool> FTPDownload(string filePath, string fileName, string FTPAddress, string username, string password)
{
    SynchronizationContext uiContext = SynchronizationContext.Current;
    try
    {
        return await Task.Run(() =>
        {
            FtpWebRequest requestFTP;
            FileStream outputStream = new FileStream(filePath + "\\" + fileName, FileMode.Create);
            requestFTP = (FtpWebRequest) FtpWebRequest.Create(new Uri("ftp://" + FTPAddress + "/" + fileName));
            requestFTP.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DownloadFile;
            requestFTP.UseBinary = true;
            requestFTP.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(username, password);
            FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse) requestFTP.GetResponse();
            Stream ftpStream = response.GetResponseStream();
            long cl = response.ContentLength;
            int bufferSize = 1048;
            int readCount;
            byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
            int totalReadBytesCount = 0;
            readCount = ftpStream.Read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
            while (readCount > 0)
            {
                outputStream.Write(buffer, 0, readCount);
                readCount = ftpStream.Read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                uiContext.Send(state =>
                {
                    label1.Text = readCount.ToString();
                }, null);
            }
            ftpStream.Close();
            outputStream.Close();
            response.Close();
            return true;
        });
    }
    catch
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Так же можете посмотреть ответ @VladD, чтобы понять в чем была [проблема](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/316990/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%82-await-async):

Comment: Да решил проблему прочитал про BackGroundWorker