# Как работает Async/Await если не создает потоки?

Tags: c#, .net, async-await

В [документации](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/#a-namebkmkthreadsa-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B8) написано:

> Асинхронные методы используются для неблокирующих операций. Выражение
>   await в асинхронном методе не блокирует текущий поток на время
>   выполнения ожидаемой задачи. Вместо этого выражение регистрирует
>   остальную часть метода как продолжение и возвращает управление
>   вызывающему объекту асинхронного метода.

И собственно вопрос, а как достигается отзывчивость приложения?

А так же встает вопрос, если поток никаких не создается, то не создается ли иллюзия параллельной работы? Например, прыгая из контекста в контекст  Async/Await не понижается ли производительность, если все крутится в 1 потоке?

Или Async/Await не создает потоки, НО выполняется в отдельном потоке из пула потоков?

Comment: Они всего лишь указатели на точки "переключения контекста", а в каком потоке именно выполнять - не их зона ответственности.

Comment: https://dotnetfiddle.net/RSo5lX

Comment: У вас почему-то есть иллюзия, что таск — это кусок кода, который обязательно бежит в каком-то потоке. Это вовсе не так.

Comment: @VladD, если мы освобождаем поток от ожидания результата метода, что бы пока результат ожидается он делал другую работу, то где выполняется сам метод от которого мы ожидаем результат?

Comment: @iluxa1810: https://habrahabr.ru/post/216659/

Comment: @iluxa1810: Ещё по теме: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/663001/10105

Answer (score 4):

Конструкция async/await разворачивается компилятором в конечный автомат. В конечном автомате переменные вашего метода становятся полями, чем  достигается возможность запоминать состояние работы метода и продолжать его после ожидания завершения длительной операции. Async/await основан на [TAP](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/hh873175(v=vs.110).aspx) 
, поэтому новые потоки действительно могут и не создаваться, если в этом нет необходимости, и задача, поставленная в await может быть выполнена в текущем потоке. Это и не важно. Используя async/await вы добиваетесь не **параллельного** выполнения, а **асинхронного**. Конечный автомат умеет дождаться завершения длительных операций, выходящих за рамки вашего кода, таких как отправка запросов по сети, обращение к дисковой системе или СУБД. В этом и есть основное  преимущество использования async/await.

```
async Task<Model> GetModel(Func<Model, bool> condition)
{
     var model = await dbContext.Models.FirstOrDefaultAsync(condition);// здесь текущий поток освобождается, и может выполнять другую работу. Работа метода возобновиться, после получения ответа от БД
     return model;
}
```

Также следует отметить, что нужно быть внимательными и добиваться **истинной** асинхронности в коде. Истинный асинхронный код должен ставить в await только те методы, которые **действительно** освобождают поток и дожидаются выполнения операции, после чего реагируют на это. Часто такие методы основаны на [EAP](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms228969(v=vs.110).aspx). Метод FirstOrDefaultAsync - это правильный метод. Если использовать **не истинную** асинхронность это не даст возможности освобождать потоки в await, чем не только убьет возможность масштабирования кода, но может и сделать его менее эффективным, чем без использования async/await, поскольку возможна ситуация переключения контекстов выполнения.

```
async Task<Model> GetModel(Func<Model, bool> condition)
{
   var model = await Task.Run(dbContext.Models.FirstOrDefault(condition);)
   return model;
```

}
Этот код будет работать, но асинхронности здесь не будет. Потоки освобождаться не будут. Наоборот, текущий поток должен дождаться выполнения Task, которая обращается к БД. В момент когда выполнение доходит до await выполнение прерывается и текущий поток освобождается. Но код внутри Task не является асинхронным, и он заморозит поток, пока не получит ответ от БД.

Comment: `await` в примере потерялся.

Comment: Т.е, все таки поток может создастся, а может нет, может браться из пула? Просто, слишком много абстракции=(

Comment: Да, поток может как создаться, так взяться и из пула. А может выполниться и в том же потоке. Например, вот такой код await Task.Delay(0) выполниться в том же потоке