# Почему async/await блокирует UI?

Tags: c#, xamarin, async-await

Пытаюсь разобраться с async/await.

Вызываю асинхронный метод:

```
public static async Task<Data> GetData(string url)
{
    dynamic results = await DataService.getData(url);
}
```

Cам метод:

```
public static async Task<dynamic> getData(string url)
{
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    var response = await client.GetAsync(url);
    while(true){} // специально сделанное зацикливание, чтобы увидеть что UI не блокируется
    dynamic data = null;
    if(response !=null)
    {
        string json = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
        data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);
    }
    return data;
}
```

Однако при вызове этого метода всё зависает. Почему все зависает, ведь на сколько я понимаю, async\await должен создаваться в отдельном потоке и следовательно не должен блочить UI, а просто зацикливаться в "фоновом" потоке?

Comment: Нет ничего лучше чтоб заблокировать UI так это вызвать у асинх.метода Result: `string json = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Нет, вы понимаете неправильно.

Если async-функция запущена в UI-потоке, она в нём и выполняется (это можно легко увидеть, залогировав Id потока), за исключением await’ов, во время которых функция вообще нигде не выполняется (и тем самым освобождает UI-поток). Иначе как бы можно было получать доступ к UI-контролам в async-функции? Уберите вечный цикл, он завешивает UI.

Что потенциально может вывести async-функцию  в другой поток — это `ConfigureAwait(false)`, но в вашей функции его нет.

---

У вас ошибка в строке

```
string json = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
```

Вы не должны *синхронно* дожидаться завершения Task’а `ReadAsStringAsync()`. Замените это на

```
string json = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

---

Кстати, у вас есть ещё одна потенциально медленная операция в UI-потоке: `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json)`. Вынесите её в фоновый поток при помощи

```
data = await Task.Run(() => JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json));
```

---

По поводу механики (*как именно* работает async-функция на нижнем уровне) можно почитать, например, [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/491632/10105), [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/750506/10105), [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/316990/10105), [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/712636/10105), [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/662902/10105) и [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/681382/10105). И посмотреть [тут](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lh8cT6qI-nA).

Comment: дело в том, что без вечного цикла - всё работает идеально. Вечный цикл сделан для того чтобы увидеть что поток UI продолжает работать, пока поток с этим методом зависает. Добавил ConfigureAwait(false) - всё равно зависает

Comment: @a.tarasevich это случайность. Ответ сервера был небольшим и метод ReadAsStringAsync оказался выполнен синхронно. Запросите файл по-больше - и у вас без всяких вечных циклов все повиснет.

Comment: то есть если метод зависает (добавлением вечного цикла), то UI по-любому зависнет и вариантов решения нет?

Comment: @a.tarasevich как вы думаете, в каком потоке запускается `while(true){}` ?

Comment: @a.tarasevich: `ConfigureAwait(false)` лишь _потенциально_ может увести async-функцию в другой поток, он не гарантирует этого.

Comment: @a.tarasevich: В каком смысле «решения нет»? Если вы запускаете холостой цикл в UI-покоте, он, конечно, зависнет. Зачем вам вечный цикл?

Comment: всё, я понял, спасибо!

Comment: @a.tarasevich: Пожалуйста! Хорошо, что разобрались!

Comment: @VladD может было лучше пояснить, что `await` "заставляет" компилятор создавать машину состояний, а не порождать новый `Thread`?

Comment: @Bulson: Это было бы слишком длинное объяснение, тем более, что таких уже на сайте было очень много. Упрощённого объяснения («async-функция не занимает никакого потока на время await») должно вполне хватить. Лучше я попробую найти ссылку.