# Не появляется окно Windows Forms при присвоении переменной

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, асинхронность

Разбираюсь с работой с REST API в C#. Получилось так, что почему-то окно приложения Windows Forms перестало открываться, когда я вызываю свой метод для получения списка загруженных на сервер видео.

```cs
namespace TVizard_GUI
{
    public partial class MainForm : Form
    {
        public MainForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            clockLabel.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss");
        }

        private void MainForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Video[] videos = API.GetVideoListAsync().Result;
            //Array.ForEach(videos, video =>
            //{
            //    videoList.Items.Add(video.filename);
            //});
        }
    }

    public class Video
    {
        public string filename { get; set; }
        public int duration { get; set; }
        public string durationReadable { get; set; }
    }

    static class API
    {
        private static HttpClient client = new();

        public static async Task<Video[]> GetVideoListAsync()
        {
            var response = await client.GetAsync("http://localhost:3000/uploadedVideos");
            var videos = await JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsync<Video[]>(response.Content.ReadAsStream());

            return videos;
        }
    }
}
```

Когда я комментирую присвоение переменной `videos` результата исполнения функции, всё тоже начинает работать. Значит, проблема не в самой функции, а именно в моменте, когда то, что она возвращает направляется в переменную. Почему так может быть?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/767911/220553

Comment: @EvgeniyZ, из поста стало понятно только, что стоило бы заменить мой GetVideoList().Result на await. Но я не могу так сделать, потому что функция MainForm_Load не асинхронная и сделать я её такой не могу. Мне вынести всё общение с сервером в отдельный поток или что? Не совсем понимаю ход мысли.

Comment: `async void MainForm_Load(...) { var videos = await API.GetVideoListAsync(); }`. Если коротко, вызывая `.Result` и не используя `await`, ваша логика синхронна, она выполняется в UI потоке, тем самым вы его и вешаете. Не используйте асинхронные задачи без `await` и не используйте `.Result` без ожидания ( например `var task = await SomeTask();  var result = task.Result;` ).

Comment: @EvgeniyZ, я накатала стену текста о том, как не могу сделать функцию `MainForm_Load` асинхронной, чтобы потом зайти и понять, что она у меня уже была асинхронной. Мда, а ларчик просто открывался.
Спасибо за помощь.

Answer (score 1):

Решила проблему, сделав функцию `MainForm_Load` асинхронной. По какой-то причине, когда я это делала изначально, IDE выдавала мне ошибку. Скорее всего поэтому я и не дошла до этого сразу. Сейчас просто вызываю нужный метод через `await`.

```
private async void MainForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Video[] videos = await API.GetVideoListAsync();
    Array.ForEach(videos, video =>
    {
        videoList.Items.Add(video.filename);
    });
}
```

В остальном коде никаких изменений нет.