# разница Thread и Task

Tags: c#, .net, многопоточность

Можно ли утверждать что Task автоматически создает пул потоков, а Thread нет ?

Comment: немного текста от [Джона Скита](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13429164/312041)

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [task и нативный thread](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/662902/task-%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9-thread)

Comment: Прочитайте 1 и 2 главы [этого](https://professorweb.ru/my/csharp/thread_and_files/1/thread_index.php).

Answer (score 8):

Говорить что *"Task автоматически создает пул потоков"* нельзя, потому что пул потоков есть в рантайме независимо ни от каких Task. И даже говорить что Task использует пул потоков - тоже нельзя, потому что Task может работать в любом планировщике включая самые экзотические.

Однако, про такой вызов как `Task.Run`, действительно можно сказать что он всегда использует пул потоков.

---

Настоящая разница между Task и Thread - в том, что Task имеет средства не только для того чтобы начать выполнение параллельной задачи - но и для того чтобы получить результат этого выполнения.

Comment: имхо, большая разница между тредом и таском в том, что тред - это, грубо говоря, контекст выполнения инструкций, когда таск - это такая абстрактная задача. То есть это абсолютно разные понятия из разных плоскостей.

Comment: почему никто не затронул аспект выделения ресурсов для Thread, а  Task действительно использует потоки из пула, максимальный размер которого 250 потоков по умолчанию.

Comment: @DigitalCore: `Task` вовсе не обязательно использует поток из пула. Хуже того, `Task` вовсе не обязательно вообще использует поток. Пример — `Task.Delay`.

Comment: @VladD возможно я не так выразился, имелось в виду, что если Task использует поток пула - он берёт его из пула - но не создаёт сам пул!

Comment: @DigitalCore https://gist.github.com/mayorovp/513b07f9e8d3507f26b30e5b1a4fda41

Comment: почти везде пишут что таск это обещание, а thread выполнение. никак не могу понять. Разве когда мы вызываем таск, он разве не сразу идет выполнятся ?

Comment: и какое отношение имеет "обещание" к много-ядерным процессорам ?

Comment: @ShamilQurbanli: Task = обещание — да. Thread = выполнение — ну как бы тоже да. Но аналогия ложная, выполнение не обязательно этого обещания. Просто случайно совпали слова.

Comment: Тогда я так понимаю что thread это один рабочий который выполняет все, а таск это несколько рабочие. Мы звони одному из них и даем задачу, а он обещает что выполнит это. Рабочие - это аналогия к много ядерным процессорам. Я правильно понял ?

Comment: @ShamilQurbanli нет, неверная. Группа рабочих - пул потоков, выраженный планировщиком задач по умолчанию. А Task - это как раз обещание данное одним из них.

Comment: Таск же как thread мгновенно выполняется. Почему обещание ? Не могу понять ? Почему же обещание ?

Comment: @ShamilQurbanli Таск может мгновенно выполняться, может выполняться отложенно, может вообще не выполняться, может родиться уже выполненным, а может быть вообще не связанным с выполнением чего либо. Таск - это абстрактная операция, она не обязательно связана с выполнением какого то кода

Comment: @ShamilQurbanli он мгновенно начинает выполняться. А вот закончить выполняться он только обещает.

Comment: Каким образом обещает ? Что вообще означает обещать ? А что тогда thread делает ? Не обещая берется за работу ? Как вообще надо понять слово обещание ?

Comment: @Shamil Qurbanli  `Task = обещание — да. Thread = выполнение` я вам очень советую забыть это

Comment: @ShamilQurbanli вы всё ещё думаете, что таск обязательно исполняет какой то код. Это не так.