# Бд в C# через access

Tags: c#

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я новичок в работе с бд  на C#.  Ошибка возникает при попытке добавить данные в бд. На других формах тот же самый код работает без проблем[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string number = textBox1.Text;
    string fio = textBox2.Text.ToString();
    string gr = comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();    
    string text = "insert into students(nomer, fio, group) VALUES('number','" + 
    fio + "','" + gr + "')";
    OleDbCommand data = new OleDbCommand(text, myConnection);
    data.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Comment: выложите текст кода, а не его картинку!

Comment: уберите `ToString()`

Comment: уберите "'" у number!

Comment: @Monomax, а мы же до конца не знаем, схему таблицы. Может у него Number-это строка...

Comment: 1 поле тип строка

Comment: тогда у вас нет разницы между номером и фамилией, а значит нет уникальности данных.

Comment: а можно увидеть проект таблицы куда вносятся данные?

Comment: поменял название поле таблицы на другое имя. Название group принимал как ключевое

Comment: используйте $ перед строкой будет удобнее читать  что то типа  $"insert into students(nomer, fio, group) VALUES('{number}','{fio}', '{group}')";

Comment: используй Entity Framework для доступа к базам, проверяй валидность строк через RegEx, например. в самих полях ввода ограничь вводимые символы

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Вставь код вместо картинки.
2. Не уверен, но слово Group может расцениваться, как ключевое => экранируй его через `[` и `]`. Может еще и number.
3. Вставка параметров напрямую в запрос- это плохой тон и прямой путь к SQL-инъекции.
   Если пользователь введет что-то с '' в полях, то все поломается. Почитай про параметризованные запросы.
4. Если это не поможет, то в дебаге возьмите из переменной Text текст запроса и выполните его в Access и он подсветит место, где косяк.

Comment: судя по картинке, как раз группа то и проходит нормально.

Answer (score 2):

если учесть замечания 3 от @iluxa1810
как то так будет безопасней

Синхроничная версия метода:

```
    public void Insert(String connectionString)
    {
        var number = textBox1.Text;
        var fio = textBox2.Text;
        var gr = comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();

        using (var connection = new OleDbConnection(connectionString))
        {
            using (var command = connection.CreateCommand())
            {
                command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO STUDENTS (number, fio, group) VALUES(@number,  @fio, @gr)";
                command.Parameters.AddRange(new OleDbParameter[] 
                {
                    new OleDbParameter("@number", number),
                    new OleDbParameter("@fio", fio),
                    new OleDbParameter("@gr", gr)
                });

                connection.Open();
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }    
        }   
    }
```

Асинхронная версия метода:

```
    public async void InsertAsync(String connectionString)
    {
        var number = textBox1.Text;
        var fio = textBox2.Text;
        var gr = comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();

        using (var connection = new OleDbConnection(connectionString))
        {
            using (var command = connection.CreateCommand())
            {
                command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO STUDENTS (number, fio, group) VALUES(@number,  @fio, @gr)";
                command.Parameters.AddRange(new OleDbParameter[]
                {
                    new OleDbParameter("@number", number),
                    new OleDbParameter("@fio", fio),
                    new OleDbParameter("@gr", gr)
                });

                await connection.OpenAsync();
                await command.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();
            }  
        }
    }
```

Comment: Слишком сложна... Я бы убрал бы асинхронность. Так как может быть ТС только начал изучать язык, а тут мы ему сразу показываем высокоуровневые конструкции, которые могут ввести в ступор.

Comment: в общем, сложновато, за то эффективно) сейчас поправлю

Comment: Не спорю, но вопрос не об этом. Можно было еще написать "WinForms фигня, вот делай на WPF".:)

Comment: Минус за такую _асинхронность_. Нахрена тут `Task.Run`? | `OpenAsync` и `ExecuteReaderAsync` без await'а - facepalm...

Comment: `ToString` у свойств `Text` не нужны. Хоть это и не ошибка, но всё же.

Comment: @Alexander Petrov, я знаю, просто это копи паст, того что автор выложил)

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, а что не так с асихнронностью?  Запустили новый Task и вернули управление, а в вызывающем коде продолжили какую-то работу и когда нам нужен результат повесили await. Не так часто использовал asyn/await.

Comment: Хотя... Вроде, тут https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18013523/when-correctly-use-task-run-and-when-just-async-await вычитал. Реальный Task имеет смысл делать, когда CPU-BOUND операция работает, а у нас тут IO. Так?

Comment: @iluxa1810 - Да, Task нужен для CPU-bound операций. А в данном случае имеются настоящие IO-bound методы `OpenAsync`/`ExecuteReaderAsync` - вот на них и нужно await'ить.

Comment: [Task.Run Etiquette](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/10/taskrun-etiquette-and-proper-usage.html) - полезная ссылка. @iluxa1810

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, а что за Task'и возвращают OpenAsync и ExecuteReaderAsync? Ведь там же, по идее за кулисами вызывается такой же Task.Run, который породит потоки. Единственное только скорее всего они возьмутся из пула.

Comment: @iluxa1810 - CPU-bound - создается поток. IO-bound - настоящего потока нет, будет аппаратное ожидание на портах IOCP. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/662902/184217

Comment: @Alexander Petrov, спасибо за коммент, я этим вопросом никогда даже не задавался)

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, исправил замечания `Минус за такую асинхронность. Нахрена тут Task.Run? | OpenAsync и ExecuteReaderAsync без await'а - facepalm...` теперь должно быть все норм.

Comment: В обеих версиях: `command` обернуть в `using`, использовать `ExecuteNonQuery(Async)`.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, а что это нам дает ExecuteNonQuery(Async)

Comment: Insert не возвращает данные, поэтому не нужен reader.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, а понял. Получается маленькая оптимизация)

Answer (score 0):

У вас не правильно сформулирован запрос на вставку, если вы не хотите делать параметризованный запрос в БД, то исправьте код:

```
string text ="insert into students (number,fio,group) VALUES('"+number+"','"+fio+"','"+gr+"')";
```

Драйвер БД ругается на совпадения номера с фамилией!

Comment: Не компилятор, а драйвер БД :)

Comment: @iluxa1810 согласен, не проснулся еще.