Как Task понимает, что он уже выполнен, если поток освобожден?
К примеру, если я асинхронно обращусь в БД с запросом. Как Task должна понять, что он уже выполнил и поменял свой статус? Правильно понимаю ли я, что когда я обращаюсь к БД асинхронно, по сути никакой поток его не ждет или освобождается только вызывающий поток, а за ним есть дополнительный поток, который ждет ответа от БД?

https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/663039/184217 - тут я кратко описал как смог различие IO и CPU операций. При обращении к БД за окончанием операции будет следить "железо" - контроллер сети/диска.

There Is No Thread
