# Async Await использует время в потоке когда метод активен

Tags: .net, async-await

Асинхронный метод не требует отдельного потока, выполняется в текущем контексте синхронизации. +

Что означает: - "использует время в потоке, только когда метод активен"?

Async метод возвращает управление внешнему коду и одновременно выполняется в том же потоке только когда активен?

Какой смысл этой фразы?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Заранее спасибо!

Ресурс: https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/index

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Когда вызывается [`async`](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/461099/194837)-метод, происходит следующее:
Начинает синхронно выполняться `async`-метод. Если этот метод заканчивается до первого `await`, результат доставляется синхронно, и из метода возвращается уже закончившийся, завершённый `Task`. Если в процессе выполнения встретился `await`, система проверяет, отработало ли уже задание, на которое вызывался `await`. Если это задание отработало, то подставляется его результат, и синхронное выполнение продолжается дальше. Если задание, на которое происходит `await`, ещё не отработало, в этот момент из метода возвращается **незавершённый Task**. Метод помечается как **выполняющийся** и управление возвращается внешнему коду. В этой точке внешний код получает управление и продолжает выполняться. И поскольку этот `Task` ещё не завершён, внешний код в этот момент аналогично отдаст управление ещё более внешнему коду. Когда `Task`, на который происходит `await`, завершится (произведя результат или исключение), код после `await` возобновит свою работу. Это все значит, что когда синхронно выполняется `async`-метод, он использует время основного потока пока она выполняется, а не занимает время работы основного потока.

> Таким образом получается, что если не активен основной поток, в котором выполняется `async`-метод, то не работает и метод `async`. Вот и отсюда это выражение - "использует время в потоке, только когда метод активен".

Comment: ինդձ թվում է, ես սա արդեն [այստեղ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/461099/10105) էի տեսել :)

Comment: @VladD Это значит что ты арменин или просто пример исползования гугл  переводчика?и да ճիշտ ես տեսել,եթե չեմ սխալվում քո գրած պատասխանն է,но все же читать не вредно ;)

Comment: Я не армянин, но мир же тесен, и друзья-армяне у меня найдутся. Но всё же, если цитируешь, ставь ссылку на оригинал. Peace! :)

Comment: окай добавлен уже ;)