# Async и Await. Контекст синхронизации и выполнения.Конечный автомат. C#

Tags: c#, .net, async-await

Добрый день.Читаю про async и await (Джон Скит) и не могу никак понять момент про контекст синхронизации и контекст выполнения.Может кто - нибудь изложить или направить где почитать об этом более простым языком.Я правильно понимаю что async-await не создает новый поток,а работает в текущем ? И как при этом помогает ConfigureAwait

Answer (score 21):

Нет-нет, `async`/`await` вообще не работает с потоками.

Смотрите, на самом деле `async`-функция — это вовсе не функция в привычном понимании этого слова. С внешней стороны она выглядит как функция, возвращающая `Task`. Но если мы посмотрим изнутри, то приход наружу возвращаемого значения не означает, что код функции добежал до `return` или конца тела функции! Из `async`-функции возвращается обычно незавершённый `Task`.

Стойте, а что это за зверь — `Task`? Это абстракция, которая представляет собой какое-то задание, выполнение которого завершится в какой-то момент.* Для `async`-функции задание — это выполнить саму функцию, и это самое задание завершится в момент, когда функция с точки зрения своего внутреннего выполнения добежит до `return`.

Так вот, пусть у нас есть async-функция `F`:

```
async Task F()
{
    var seconds = new Random().Next(10);
    await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(seconds));
}
```

Когда мы пишем `Task t = F();`, то присвоение переменной `t` происходит не когда функция добежит до конца, а практически сразу**. А что соответствует окончанию работы `Task`'а? Очень просто, но это важный момент.

Когда вы напишете `await t;` (а вы можете написать это только в другом, внешнем `async`-методе!), то выполнится эта строка тогда, когда наш `Task` завершится. Причём на время ожидания завершения `t`, наше внешнее задание не будет блокировать поток, ожидая окончания внутреннего задания `t`. На время ожидания наше внешнее задание как бы не будет выполняться *нигде*, и будет существовать лишь в форме объекта. По завершению задания `t` наше внешнее задание снова «появится» и продолжит выполнение, как ни в чём ни бывало.

А причём же здесь многопоточность, спросите вы. Ну да, она тут практически не при чём. Внутреннее задание `t` может выполняться в том же, в другом, в нескольких или вообще ни в каком потоке, для `await` это неважно, `await` просто дожидается окончания задания `t`.

Просто раньше, до появления `async`/`await` для того, чтобы функция на время ожидания не блокировала всё приложение, приходилось выгружать её в другой поток. Но теперь это не нужно, т. к. `async`-функции на время ожидания по `await` не блокируют ничего, и той же функциональности можно добиться и без многопоточности.

---

Ещё два слова про `ConfigureAwait`. Когда `async`-функция возобновляет выполнение после `await`, в каком потоке она это делает? Ну вообще-то это не обязательно исходный поток, в котором она начинала свой `await` (этот поток вообще может уже завершиться!). Но есть важный частный случай: если у нас графическое приложение, и `await` начинался в UI-потоке, то продолжаться будет тоже в нём (за это отвечает тот самый контекст выполнения). Обычно это важно, т. к. доступ к UI-элементам возможен только в UI-потоке. Также есть и другие ситуации, когда вам хотелось бы вернуться после `await` в тот же поток***, в котором вы начинали `await`,

Так вот, если вам это не нужно, если вам всё равно, где будет происходить выполнение продолжения задания, то вы можете воспользоваться `ConfigureAwait(false)`, чтобы сообщить об этом фреймворку и немного облегчить ему задачу. Вот и всё. Он может этим воспользоваться, и перекинуть хвост задания на пул потоков. А может и не воспользоваться, его право.

---

Дополнительное чтение по теме:

- [Нужен async/await или не нужен?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/491632/10105)
- [Как работают await async](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/316990/10105)
- [Андрей Часовских — Async/await: собираем грабли](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lh8cT6qI-nA)

---

*Ну или никогда не завершится. Например, внутри `async`-функции можно легко устроить бесконечный цикл.

**Когда именно, можно посмотреть в [этом](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/461099/10105) более подробном описании.

***Или группу потоков. Или вообще `SynchronizationContext`.

Comment: Спасибо. Очень помогли. Многое стало понятным. Единственное не до конца понял про контекст выполнения и синхронизации

Comment: @ЗаурЯкубов: Смотрите, контекст синхронизации — это такая штука, которая умеет привести выполнение после await куда-нибудь (например, в UI-поток). Обычно контекст синхронизации равен `null` (и после `await` код продолжает выполняться на пуле потоков), но фреймворки наподобие WPF или WinForms устанавливают свой контекст синхронизации, который приводит в UI-поток.

Comment: Получается, асинхронный метод захватывает контекст выполнения, то вызывающий код не имеет доступ к контролам.?Что тогда может делать вызывающий код ? Вообще в каких случаях разумно использовать async-await ?Когда мы скачиваем какой то файл или что то еще?

Comment: @ЗаурЯкубов: Асинхронный метод не захватывает контекст выполнения (а что это значит?). Это `await` смотрит, есть ли контекст выполнения, и если есть, то по окончанию ожидания пользуется им, чтобы возобновить выполнение  в нём. (А если нет, то возобновляет выполнение на пуле потоков.) // Async/await разумно использовать всегда (кроме тех случаев, когда без ручного управления потоками не обойтись). Это предпочтительный метод для организации асинхронности.

Comment: *Асинхронный метод не захватывает контекст выполнения* А подтвердить ссылкой можете? В исходниках я вижу, что контекст исполнения (не путать с контекстом синхронизации) [захватывается](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/AsyncMethodBuilder.cs,916), а потом [восстанавливается](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/AsyncMethodBuilder.cs,1070) перед исполнением пользовательского кода.

Comment: @PetSerAl: А, перепутал с контекстом синхронизации. Фу ты ну ты :)