# не выходить из функции, пока не получен ответ от сервера C#

Tags: c#

Есть приведенный ниже код, в данном случае использую задержу выполнения Thread.Sleep , как реализовать отправку серверу (к примеру localhost/check.php) в цикле и в ожидании определенного ответа (к примеру строки), после получения ответа вернуть полученную строку через return?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using DynamicPluginData;
using System.Threading;

namespace DatacolDynamicPluginNS {
    public class DynamicPluginClass {
        public static string processDataFieldValue(string s, ItemInfo itemInfo, GlobalInfo globalInfo) {
            Thread.Sleep(20000);
            return s;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Очевидно, вам нужен цикл, например do..while

Comment: @tym32167 , к сожалению я не силен с синтаксисом C#, поэтому хотел бы узнать, как правильно отправлять запросы в цикле, чтобы при продолжительной работе приложения не "подвиснуть" его.

Comment: Правильнее эту задачу делать через async/await но если у вас проблемы с пониманием синтаксиса c#, то боюсь это будет слишком сложным для вас.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот реализация через TcpClient из одного из моих проектов.

```
public static async Task<string> Name(parametrs)
{
      var tcp = new TcpClient();
      tcp.ReceiveTimeout = {YouTimeOut};
      tcp.Client.Connect("Adress", port);

      NetworkStream stream = tcp.GetStream();
      stream.ReadTimeout = {время чтения};
      byte[] toBytes = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(E3ImageName);

      await stream.WriteAsync(toBytes, 0, toBytes.Length);

      string responseData = String.Empty;

      byte[] data = new byte[1024];
      using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
      {
           int numBytesRead;
           var cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource(180000);
           cancellationTokenSource.Token.Register(() => stream.Close());
           while ((numBytesRead = await stream.ReadAsync(data, 0, data.Length, cancellationTokenSource.Token)) > 0)
           {
               ms.Write(data, 0, numBytesRead);
           }
           responseData = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(ms.ToArray(), 0, (int)ms.Length);
      }

      tcp.Close();

      return responseData;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Если хотите написать свой метод правильно и "без велосипедов", используя современные инструменты, обратите внимание на такие конструкции языка, как класс `Task` и `async/await`.

Тут есть годный материал по данной теме

https://metanit.com/sharp/tutorial/12.1.php

https://metanit.com/sharp/tutorial/13.3.php

https://metanit.com/sharp/tutorial/13.5.php

[Как работают await async](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/316990/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%82-await-async)

Answer (score 3):

`while(true)`, `for(;;)`, а внутри уже ваш `Sleep` и проверка условия. Если звезды сошлись и получен ответ, то делаете `break`;